# Dynamically load files in D3

Tags: json, d3.js, data-visualization, networkx

I am trying to visualize a social network graph using d3. I am using the force layout method.
What I want to do is to allow the user to select a node in the graph and based on the selected node, run a python script which changes the attributes of the other nodes. And I want to reflect the changes on the graph dynamically. 
For the first part, I am using a php to run the python file and creating a new json file with the updated node attributes. But I don't know how to load this file dynamically, keeping the layout the same and reflect the changes. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="button">
    <input name="RumourSource" type="button" value="Source" onclick="SelectSource()" />
    <input name="InfoFlow" type="button" value="Info" onclick="UpdateData()" />
</div>

<script>




var width = 1500,
    height = 1500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link;
var node;

d3.json("data.json", function (graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
            .friction(0.5)
      .start();

  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
                if (d.group == 1){
                    return "red"
                }
                else{
                return "blue"
                }
                })

            .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "magenta");})
            .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");})
            .on("click", function(d){
                                                    console.log(d.name);
                                                    $.get("run_rumour_source.php", {sourceNode:d.name}, function(data,status){console.log("Data: "+ data + "\nStatus: " + status);}
                                                    );
             d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .delay(1000)
            .duration(1000)
            .style("fill", "magenta");

            updateData(node)
      <!-- .call(force.drag); -->
        })


  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });

}
);

function updateData(node){ 

        force.stop();
        d3.selectAll(".node").remove();
        d3.selectAll(".link").remove();
        var filename = "data1.json"
        var node1;
        var link1;
            d3.json(filename, function(g){          
                force
                .nodes(g.nodes)
                .links(g.links);
                console.log(g.nodes)

                node1 = svg.selectAll(".node")              
                    .data(g.nodes)
                    .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .style("fill", function(d) { 
                                            if (d.group == 1){
                                                return "red"
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                return "blue"
                                            }
                                }
                                );

            link1 = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(g.links)
            .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

                }
                );


    force.on("tick", function() {
    link1.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node1.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });

    force.start();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The procedure for doing something like this is roughly as follows.

1. Make a `d3.json` call (or equivalent) to the URL that will give you the updated data.
2. In the handler for that call, add/remove nodes and links of the force layout as appropriate. You need to modify the data structures that you passed to the force layout earlier, not create new arrays.
3. Add/remove/change visual elements (nodes, lines) as appropriate. You can use D3's `data()` function to do this.
4. Restart the force layout.